# Chartjs and ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I am working with ionic and having pages containing charts except that on the navigator the chart is perfectly showing but not on the phone. Can anyone help, please?

Here is my code. 
( I tested on android and ios )

```
showShart () { 
    if (this.lineChartData.length != 0) {

      this.chartVar = new Chart(this.chartCanvas.nativeElement, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          datasets: [{
            data: this.lineChartData,
            backgroundColor: '',
            borderColor: '#1DE9B6',
            pointBackgroundColor: '#1DE9B6',
            pointBorderColor: '#fff',
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
            pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
          }],
          labels: this.dates

        },

        options: {
          legend: {
            display: false
          },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: "Evolution de votre pression systolique",
            fontColor: "#12b0bc",
            fontSize: 18,
            fontStyle: 'normal',
            fontFamily: "'Quicksand'"

          },
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: "Date"
              }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: "Pression systolique"
              },
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: false,
              }
            }]

          },

          responsive: true
        }

      })
    }

}
```

Comment: where are you calling `showShart ()`

Comment: in the ngAfterViewInit ()

Comment: any errors on console?

Comment: no not at all !

Comment: Which android version?.. seems like there is an open bug https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4570